# ionic 4 Native Audio cant find my mp3 files

Tags: cordova, ionic4

I try to use `@ionic-native/native-audio` with below code to load my mp3 files

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/

```
this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple(‘sound2’, ‘assets/sound2.mp3’.then(() => {
  console.log(‘preload success’)
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

However i get a error when preload the mp3 `java.io.FileNotFoundException: www/assets/sound2.mp3`
I am sure the `sound2.mp3` is placed in both `/src/assets/sound2.mp3` and `www/assets/sound2.mp3`
Anyone got any ideas on it?

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue with `Ionic 6.18.1`, `cordova-plugin-nativeaudio@3.0.9` and `Capacitor 3.3.2`. Such issues with old Cordova plugins are regular so better to add a hook with a fix, so no need to change it manually after every `sync`.

Add to `package.json` in the `scripts` block:

`"capacitor:sync:after": "node ./scripts/fix-audio-plugin.js"`

Add a new file to `scripts/fix-audio-plugin.js`:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

const fixPathInFile = (filePath) => {
  let content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
  if (content) {
    let replaced = false;
    content = content.replaceAll('www', () => {
      replaced = true;
      return 'public';
    });
    if (replaced) {
      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, content);
    }
  } else {
    console.error('file NativeAudio not found!');
  }
}

if (process.env.CAPACITOR_PLATFORM_NAME === 'android') {
  let filePath = './android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/java/com/rjfun/cordova/plugin/nativeaudio/NativeAudio.java';
  fixPathInFile(filePath);
} else if (process.env.CAPACITOR_PLATFORM_NAME === 'ios') {
  let filePath = './ios/capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins/sources/CordovaPluginNativeaudio/NativeAudio.m';
  fixPathInFile(filePath);
}
```

Run `ionic cap sync` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

**quick fix**

go to:
"your-app\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\com\rjfun\cordova\plugin\nativeaudio\NativeAudio.java"

then:
change the code line

```
String fullPath = "www/".concat(assetPath)
```

to

```
String fullPath = "public/".concat(assetPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to access 'www/assets' for Android device:

```
let filePath = this.file.applicationDirectory + 'public/assets/';
```

If not working try to copy file before with the File Cordova Plugin:

```
import { File } from "@ionic-native/file/ngx";

constructor(private file: File) { }


yourFonction(){
if(this.platform.is('android')){
  let filePath = this.file.applicationDirectory + 'public/assets/';

  this.file.copyFile(filePath, fileName, this.file.externalCacheDirectory, fileName)
    .then( () => alert('File copied in :' +  this.file.externalCacheDirectory))
    .catch(e => alert("Error copying file => " + JSON.stringify(e));

    //then perform audio preload accessing the copied file in device storage

}else{
    IOS device action...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/native-audio-asset-not-found-ios/78817/16 which said this.

**Solution**
Cordova Native Audio plugin expects an assets "www" folder. But in an Ionic Capacitor project it’s named "public".
As the plugin has this value hard coded, the solution in the link below tells you to dive in the plugin source code inside each platform and replace “www” with “public”.

Alternatively add a symlink from the "www" folder to the "public" folder in the platform main/assets location.

See this issue for more info:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2685

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we went into plugin issues of this type of category. To solve it we must edit native code inside source folder.

1. Capacitor uses "public/..." instead of "www/..." (which was used by cordova).
2. Hope you are in capacitor project.
3. Go to {project_folder}/node_modules/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio/src/android.
4. Open NativeAudio.java. Search for "String fullPath" and replace the "www" with "public". Run "ionic cap sync android".
5. That's it. Now your file is accessible inside native app.

And a question. I am unable to play mp3 file. But wav file works. How it works?