# ERROR: @capacitor-community/native-audio - Asset Path is missing [IONIC 5]

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, capacitor, ionic5, capacitor-plugin

I have a problem when I want to preload a sound on my IONIC 5 app.

In my xcode the following error is displayed:

> {"message":"Asset Path is missing - forward.mp3","errorMessage":"Asset
> Path is missing - forward.mp3"}

However, my code is the following and seems to respect the way of using the plugin:

**In my page.ts**

```
import {NativeAudio} from '@capacitor-community/native-audio';

  ngOnInit() {
    NativeAudio.preload({
      assetId: 'forward',
      assetPath: 'forward.mp3',
      audioChannelNum: 1,
      isUrl: false
  });
}
```

I created a "sounds" folder in "ios / App / App" which contains my forward.mp3 file.

I also tried to call the relative file which is "src/assets/audios/forward.mp3" but I get the same error.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Add `public/` in front of your route. This may only work for ios. You should also put it in your assets folder. If there is no assets folder, create one in your root directory. Including a subdirectory for audio may also be smart. Example: `assetPath: 'public/assets/audio/forward.mp3'`

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer in answer for cordova plugin. I didn't used capacitor's one.
Install cordova native audio plugin
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio 
and try this...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68735700/16377205
This worked for me